# Why declare an inital non-nil value to NSInteger before setting the intended value

Tags: objective-c

This code is taken from Apples documentation on [Storing Preferences in iCloud](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/StoringPreferenceDatainiCloud/StoringPreferenceDatainiCloud.html):

```
NSInteger reason = -1;

reason = [reasonForChange integerValue];

if ((reason == NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreServerChange) ||
    (reason == NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreInitialSyncChange)) {
    ...
```

What is the reason for declaring `reason` as a non-nil value?

What is wrong with directly declaring the `NSInteger` from the `integerValue` call?

```
NSInteger = [reasonForChange integerValue];

if ((reason == NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreServerChange) ||
    (reason == NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreInitialSyncChange)) {
    ...
```

It seems to be a different situation but if I need to declare a something outside of the scope it will be set I normally do something like this:

```
NSInteger reason;

if (something) {
    reason = [reasonForChange integerValue];
}
```

Is that incorrect? Is it something to do with it being an `NSInteger`? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You you observe possible values for reason default value 0 is also possible value. Please check enum below

```
NS_ENUM(NSInteger) {
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreServerChange NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_7, 5_0),
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreInitialSyncChange NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_7, 5_0),
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreQuotaViolationChange NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_7, 5_0),
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreAccountChange NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_8, 6_0)
```

};

If you write something like this

```
NSInteger reason;

if (something) {
    reason = [reasonForChange integerValue];
}
```

Even if something is false the following if condition will succeed.

```
if ((reason == NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreServerChange) ||
    (reason == NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreInitialSyncChange)) {

...
```

There for you have to initiate as

```
NSInteger reason = -1;
```

Comment: This is the answer. I knew I was missing something, the ENUM threw me off, of course 0 is a possible value. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> What is the reason for declaring `reason` as a non-nil value?

There is no point in doing that. A shorter declaration/initialization that you show below, i.e.

```
NSInteger reason = [reasonForChange integerValue];
```

would work just fine, because there is no code path that leaves `reason` unchanged. In other words, the `-1` value assigned on initialization is never read by the program, making the assignment unnecessary.

> if I need to declare a something outside of the scope it will be set I normally do something like this:
>
> ```
> NSInteger reason;
>
> if (something) {
>     reason = [reasonForChange integerValue];
> }
> ```
>
> Is that incorrect?

Yes, that would be incorrect, because when `something` evaluates to `NO`, the value of `reason` remains uninitialized. In this situation you should provide `reason` with an initial value, because reading an uninitialized local variable is undefined behavior.